# Reload the form with updated data when its call C# winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I have a main form and inside the main form I added a splitContainer to divide form into tow section panel1 and panel2. In the panel1 I added menu buttons **Company** button to open Company Form and **Distribution** button to open Distribution form and I have created relation between these.
When I insert a new company and go to adding its distribution in distribution form the company that I was inserted can't showing in combobox.
The main problem is my distribution form can't reload to get updated data from db its only hide and show the form.
I want to reopen or reload form when its call.
[Company Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeCoT.jpg) |
[Distribution Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEU9V.jpg)

Comment: Why can't you get updated data?  How do you get your data in the first place and what prevents you from repeating that process?

Comment: Perhaps, you should not load data in the `Form.Load` event, but say using method `LoadAllData`, and keep a `public bool` property to track if the data reload is required or not. Now in your `Form.Show`, you can call `if (ReloadRequired) LoadAllData()`. This way you can control `ReloadRequired` from outside the form and successfully refresh the data

Comment: When I rerun my application then its show new data in distribution combobox because I use show method to show the form when button click and its just simple showing the form but not to reload the form to show updated data that I inserted after application run. Simply I want to close this from when another is open. The problem is after running app the all form are just show and hide when its call and show method can not get the data that I inserted after app run. I hop are you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

In main form Distribution button click event call distribution from loaddata custom method to load updated date when button is clicking.

> Solution Code

```cs
    namespace ChildrenChoicePOS
    {
        public partial class Main : Form
        {
            CompanyForm companyForm = new CompanyForm();
            DistributionForm distributionForm = new DistributionForm();
            public Main()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                activeBar.Top = btnCompany.Top;
                activeBar.Height = btnCompany.Height;
            }
            private void btnDistribution_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                distributionForm.loadData();
                all_form();
                distributionForm.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```